# How to fix Expected ")" while finding an element by Xpath?

Tags: python

> Hello, this is the code :

```
  x = w.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="booking-experience-container"]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/span")
```

> This is the error everytime :

```
Expected ")" at booking-experience-container
```

> Pls guide me how to fix this issue.

Comment: use `'` instead of `"`

Answer (score 3):

**Why it happens:**

Python doesn't guess where string ends, it just tries to pair the same quote types.

In here it mean that python sees `"//*[@id="` as finished string (see how the thing is coloured in your IDE or even here!) and expects you to close the parenthesis after it... which it the same as closing parens before `booking-experience-container` - that's why you get `Expected ")" at booking-experience-container`

**Solution:**

Use different quote types. Python allows strings to use both single and double quotes, so we just need to change them:

```py
x = w.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="booking-experience-container"]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/span')
```

If we have to use same type of quotes inside, we can escape them. Escape codes/sequences in strings mean anything preceded by a backslash.

```py
x = w.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"booking-experience-container\"]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/span")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like that:

```
x = w.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="booking-experience-container"]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/span')
```

Too many double quotes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the quotes inside a string, you need to use the escape character (\) before the quotes inside the string.

In this case you should write the following line:

```
  x = w.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"booking-experience-container\"]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/span")
```

Another option could be using a simple quotation mark to define the string:

```
  x = w.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="booking-experience-container"]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/span')
```